# What is the area of the shaded region in this rectangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

What is the area of the shaded region below?
[image]
I think the solution requires subtracting the area of each of the four triangles from the area of the rectangle. I can calculate the area of triangles a and b since I have a base and height. But I don't see how to calculate the height of triangles c and d.

I've tried drawing a line parallel to the 3 cm width of the rectangle that intersects with the point where triangles c and d touch. The height of that line (call it h) along the 4 cm height of the rectangle would give me the height of both triangles c and d. But I don't see how to derive h.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each of the shaded triangles, the length of a *vertical* line from the top corner until it hits the bottom side is $2$. The *horizontal* distance between the two other corners is $\frac 32$. So the area of each shaded triangle is $\frac12\cdot 2\cdot \frac32$.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't follow this.  How do we know the vertical distance is 2?  Why does half the product of these two distances give the area of the triangle?  Would you please add a little more detail?

Comment: @saulspatz: Divide each of the shaded triangles in two by a vertical line through the top corner, and use that as the _base_ for computing the area of each of the parts. The length of the common base is $2$ because the vertical line hits the opposite side just midway between the top and bottom of the rectangle. The sum of the altitudes to each side is $\frac12+1=\frac32$.

Comment: I see it now, thanks.

Comment: Although @CYAries' answer and this one both give the same answer, I'm accepting this one because it doesn't require proving the heights of c and d must be in the ratio 1 : 3.

Answer (score 16):

The heights of $c$ and $d$ are in the ratio $1:3$ (equal to the ratio of their bases). So the heights are $1$ and $3$ respectively.

The area is $$3\times 4-\frac{1}{2}\times 1\times 4-\frac{1}{2}\times 1\times 4-\frac{1}{2}\times 1\times 1-\frac{1}{2}\times 3\times 3$$

Comment: How do I prove that the heights of c and d are equal to the ratio of their bases?

Comment: @DarylSpitzer: Bisect both c and d by a vertical line, dividing them each into a pair of right triangles.  The right triangles forming c are similar to those forming d, since they are right triangles that have another angle the same (the angles at the point common to c and d).  Thus, the ratio between the bases of c and d is the same as the ratio of the heights of c and d.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert How do I know the angles at the point common to c and d are the same?

Comment: @DarylSpitzer: Because they are vertical angles and therefore congruent.  Incidentally, whenever you see vertical triangles like this, they are similar, which immediately clarifies the whole issue.

Comment: @DarylSpitzer two pairs of angles are alternate, the other vertically opposite.

Comment: @Daryl Spitzer The two triangles are similar because they have a pair of alternate angles of parallel lines. Similar triangles have equal ratios for all corresponding linear measurements. The ratio of bases is equal to the ratio of corresponding sides, the ratio of sides, and the ratio of heights. It doesn't matter whether they are isosceles

Comment: Even if the top side is divided into portions of 0.5cm, 1cm, 1.5cm, the answer is still the same. The answer is 3 as long as the top vertices are 1 cm apart

Comment: The ratio of the corresponding sides of the pair of triangles yields another solution. The ratio of the area of the smallest triangle to that of one of the two shaded triangle is 1:3. So,

Comment: So, the area of the shaded region is $2\times 3 \times \frac{1}{2}\times 1\times 1$

Comment: We also have the square of the area of one of the two shaded triangles is equal to the product of the areas of the top triangle and the bottom triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Following from `@CY Aries` answer about c and d ratio. We can see 2 triangles (the grey arreas including the d area in each one).So we find the area of that two(4*3/2 *2) and substracting d area 2 times (3*3) gives as 3

Comment: This is a clever way to confirm the answer, but requires the area of d.

Comment: We know both he base and the height od the d triangle

Comment: How do we know the height of triangle d?

Comment: acorind to  CY Aries answer it's 1/3 ration with height of c

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is given below.

In the following Ax is the area of one of the shaded regions.

The total square give us:

$$Aa + Ab + Ac + Ad + 2\times Ax = 4\times 3$$

$$2 + 2 + \frac{1}{2}\times Hc + \frac{3}{2} \times Hd + 2\times Ax = 12$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\times Hc + \frac{3}{2} \times Hd + 2\times Ax = 8$$

The triangle made up by a, c and one shade region gives us:

$$Aa + Ac + Ax = \frac{1}{2}\times 4\times 2$$

$$2 + \frac{1}{2}\times Hc + Ax = 4 $$

$$\frac{1}{2}\times Hc + Ax = 2 $$

The height of the square give us:

$$Hc + Hd = 4$$

Now we have 3 equations with 3 unknown which is easy to solve, i.e.

$$\frac{1}{2}\times Hc + \frac{3}{2} \times Hd + 2\times Ax = 8$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\times Hc + Ax = 2 $$

$$Hc + Hd = 4$$

will give:

$$Hc = 1$$
$$Hd = 3$$
$$Ax = \frac{3}{2}$$